# Excel Macro to search for 3 items in a row and delete that row if they are there?

Tags: vba, excel

I am really new to this and I made a couple macros so far but they were easy compared to this. I think this requires actual programming.

I need to search in column A for a term. Then if it is there I need to search column B for a formatting. Then if those are true I need to search column C for a term. If all 3 are true I need to delete the row. Could someone please help?

I had this code so far and this is the only thing I had under the macro. I thought I was close but it wasn't working.

```
Dim lngRow As Long 
Dim lngRows As Long 
'Find the last row in Column A 
lngRows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 

For lngRow = lngRows To 2 Step -1 
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(lngRow, "A").Value = "No Longer Employed" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(lngRow, "E").Style = "Bad" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(lngRow, "I").Value = "Hire Date" Then
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(lngRow).EntireRow.Delete 
    End If
Next
```

Comment: sure you have to search for  'Columns("E:E").Style' not 'Value'?

Comment: `LCase(Columns("A:A").Value) = "No Longer Employed"`...if it is lower case you need to remove the capitals from inside the quote.

Comment: You are comparing full columns, you must do it row per row (and start from the end) in a loop

Comment: @Salek I am not "Sure" because I am new, but I already run another macro that searches for duplicate entries and highlights them. I want it to search for the highlighted entries IF they are part of the No Longer Employed row. Then if those are true, see if it says hire date in the third column. If those are all true then delete the row.

Comment: @VincentG Ok I looked up another example of doing the loop but I couldn't get that one to work either. I can keep trying. Would you have a simple example to loop through rows?

Comment: What did you try?  How did it not work?  Have you fixed the issue with your IF statement yet?

Comment: @rdster I have edited a bit but I now have syntax error but I think I am close. I have been trying to patch examples together haha. Here is what I have now,  not sure how to format it...

Comment: Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngRows As Long
    'Find the last row in Column A
    lngRows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     
    For lngRow = lngRows To 2 Step -1
         If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cell(lngRow, "A").Value = "No Longer Employed" And
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(lngRow, "E").Style = "Bad" And
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(lngRow, "I").Value = "Hire Date" Then
            .Rows(lngRow).EntireRow.Delete
    Next

Comment: Edit that code into your question, it is too hard to read in the comments

Comment: @rdster ok I have changed it

Comment: what happens when you try to step through your code using F8 key? Does the body of the loop execute, or not? If not, the problem would seem to be how you identify "last row". If so, then we need more detail on what you mean by "it's not working" -- because we can't read your mind.

Comment: @DavidZemens I have changed the main post to what I have now. It was giving me a syntax error on the first line of the If. I have since gotten rid of the multiple lines and put the And's on the same line and it got rid of the errors. But I run it and it doesn't do anything...

Comment: @DavidZemens Oh it is Cells on my screen. I must have deleted it editing the post. the main post is what I currently have now. It doesn't say anything wrong when compiling. but when I run it, it does nothing.

Comment: What happens when you *step through the code*? What values do you observe for `lngRow`? Is this value what you expect it to be?

Comment: @DavidZemens It shows row 245 which is the last row of text. that looks right. Nothing happens when I step through it. No errors. When I keep going I can see that lngRows changes to 244, 243, 242 and so on. So it goes through it. is my delete function correct? or am I able to do the style function like that?

Comment: OK then, it is now obvious that one (or more) of your three conditions are not being met for any of the cells. The usual culprit is leading/trailing whitespace, i.e., `"Hire Date   "` is not equivalent to `"Hire Date"`. Please verify the values in your cells conform to the values in your code. Also confirm the style name.

Comment: @DavidZemens ok So I THINK that my style isn't actually Bad. They are highlighted red and red text just like bad, but when I really look at it it looks like it is a different font and text size. I didn't realize that. Im going to fix that then see if it works.

Comment: @DavidZemens OMG IT WORKED. I was using a very close style but it wasn't the actual style. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
Dim indexRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Dim keyA, keyE, keyI As String
Dim colA, colE, colI As Integer


keyA = "No Longer Employed"
keyE = "Bad"
keyI = "Hire Date"

colA = 1 ' index of col A
colE = 5 ' index of col E
colI = 9 ' index of col I


indexRow = 2 ' starting Row number from where start the loop 

'Find the last row in Column A
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For indexRow = indexRow To LastRow Step 1 ' this loop increments the indexRow  value

If ActiveSheet.Cells(indexRow, colA).Value = keyA Then
   If ActiveSheet.Cells(indexRow, colE).Value = keyE Then
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(indexRow, colI).Value = keyI Then

            ActiveSheet.Rows(indexRow).EntireRow.Delete
            indexRow = indexRow - 1 ' because we have just deleted one row

        End If
    End If
   End If

Next
```

Comment: The generally preferred way to loop and delete from a collection is to do the loop with `Step -1`, this avoids the need to re-index the collection (`index -= 1`) and other related pitfalls. Otherwise this code is functionally equivalent to OP's code and probably does not solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your time to help me. I believe that I got it working but if for some reason mine doesn't work the way I wanted I will check into this way. As for now, mine seems to be working now.